# Select TOP 5 only returning one row when called through code, where same script returns 5 rows in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

When using the following block of code to pull the top 5 records, I get wildly different results than running the same script in SQL Sever 2008.

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
string cmdTxt = String.Format("select top 5 ID, NAME from TABLE where ID like @ID or NAME like @NAME order by ID asc");
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdTxt, Butch.connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = IdBox.Text + "%";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.Char, 65).Value = IdBox.Text + "%";
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
           adapter.Fill(results);
 }
```

For example passing the parameter '0' into IdBox, I get one row in results with the Id '01', but in SQL Server I get 5 rows back with Id's '000001', '000002', '000003', '000004', '000005'. Passing '00' instead will return zero rows from my code, but the same 5 from SQL Server. If I pass '00000' I will get the same results from code as I do from SQL sever.

Is there anyway of making my code return the same results of my SQL query? I have tried using more wild card symbols in my code parameters in case it was only checking it against one character, however that didn't work. I have the same code working elsewhere that uses a NVarChar SqlDataType, but I don't know why it isn't working here.

Comment: what is the point of calling `string.Format` with only one parameter?

Comment: Are you sure your columns are `Char`, not `VarChar` nor `NVarChar`? None of your examples are `Char(15)`.

Comment: @DourHighArch according to the design mode that column is Char(15)

Comment: @RufusL I copied the code block from another place that used multiple parameters. I could get rid of it I suppose. Does it add any extra overhead having it vs not having it?

Comment: you are using the same value for both ID and Name? Is it how you are running your SQL query as well?

Comment: @sammy yes i am. i copied and pasted the query from code and replaced  the param with the same value i used in the textbox for both parameters

Comment: Yes, you should remove the call to `string.Format` if you don't need it, and just assign the string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlDbType.Char` corresponds to `CHAR`, which is blank padded, if needed, to be exactly the length given.

Your query ends up being something like:

```
select top 5 ID, NAME from TABLE where ID like '0%             ' or NAME like '%                                                                ' order by ID asc
```

And that pattern(s) just won't match.

Try `SqlDbType.VarChar` or `SqlDbType.NVarChar` (if the corresponding column is `N...` too).

Comment: You forgot the `0` for the `NAME` comparison. And I think I would say "for the parameters" just to be clear.

Comment: Hmm, did not know that. thanks for the info. i will contact our DBA and ask if the column can have its type changed or if there is a reason that it needs to be a Char. if that works, ill come back and accept, in the meantime here is an upvote for your help

Comment: @Dragonrage: It should suffice if you use another type. On the DBMS the types are compatible regarding the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: @stickybit oh, that does indeed work. I changed the parameter types to VarChar of the same length and everything seems to be working as I need it to.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i tend to give it a day or so before accepting. that seems to be the general consensus across most sites im active on